# C# project reference not working - .dll not in output folder as it's only used in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll

At my job we've been running into an issue regarding project references lately.

I have one entry project called `EntryPoint` which references my main project, called `MainProject`. My main project has a reference added to another important project called `ImportantProject`, which contains an important `ResourceDictionary` in a file called `ImportantResources.xaml`.

I have a `Window` in my main project which uses the important `ResourceDictionary` with the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ImportantProject;component/ImportantResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

While I am designing my `Window` everything works flawlessly, I have full access to the important project's resources. However when I run my program, it immediately crashes.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '11' and line position '18'.

When I look at my output folder (`/EntryPoint/bin/Debug`), I notice that there is no `ImportantProject.dll` file, which I assume is why the crash is happening.

How can I make sure the .dll file appears in the output folder?
I would like a global solution, which works for all `Important`projects that might appear in the future if possible.

[Here's a full code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/ManIkWeet/ReferenceIssue/)

Comment: If you add a **code** reference to a member of that project - a field declaration will be enough - it will be included in the output.

Comment: This does work, but it's not a global solution to the problem. That means that any developer at my job could run into the same issue months later, and again spend hours on it...

Comment: It seems to be a known bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652785/visual-studio-does-not-copy-referenced-assemblies-through-the-reference-hierarchy

Comment: @Tom Oh good it's closed as "won't fix", thanks Microsoft...

Answer (score 1):

EntryPoint doesn't appear to have a reference to ImportantProject. If you add the reference to ImportantProject, it runs fine.

If you have project A that references project B that references project C, then project A needs to have references to both projects B and C.

Comment: This feels like an incorrect behavior to me, project A should already know that project B requires project C, as project B has a reference to C... Also if I manually add it and use a context menu item `Optimize references`, it removes project A's reference to project C...

Comment: Optimize References (R#?) has a pretty bad track record with late binding references. I'm going to assume that ResourceDictionary styles fall under that category.

Comment: It could be ReSharper, I guess that it works by looking at the references included in the .dll files, which doesn't happen on references only used by XAML.